# how to remove unuseful array items in preg_match_all result?

Tags: php, regex

how to remove unuseful array items in preg_match_all result?

some of the items in the regex is not useful for me , I don't want them display in my $result array , how can I do it? I remmbered that preg_match can remove not useful "(xxx)" when get the result , but i don't remember how to code it now

```
<?php 

$url='http://www.new_pm.com/fr/lookbook/2.html';
preg_match_all('@([a-z]{2})?(lookbook)/?(\d+)?(\.html)?@',$url,$result);
print_r($result);

/* ------- 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => lookbook/2.html
        )

    [1] => Array    // I don't want $result has this item
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => lookbook
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array    // I don't want $result has this item
        (
            [0] => .html
        )

)
 ------- */
?>
```

Comment: Remove the `()` from around the matches you no longer want... i.e. `(\.html)` becomes `\.html`

Comment: The `([a-z]{2})?` seems to be intended to match the `fr` in your example string. is the regex working as you expect it to right now? Or is `fr` not useful?

Comment: I would suggest replacing the capturing groups by non-capturing groups for now: `(?:[a-z]{2})?(lookbook)\/?(\d+)?(?:\.html)?` (I have put `?:` at the start of the capture groups). Here's a [demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/eM0eT6). Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you add parentheses into a pattern, that *captures* whatever was matched inside those parentheses and returns it in the result. Not only can this be annoying as in your case, it's also unnecessary overhead. For those reasons, whenever you don't actually need the result, either remove the parentheses (if possible) or use a non-capturing group `(?:...)` if you do need the grouping:

```
@(?:[a-z]{2})?(lookbook)/?(\d+)?(?:\.html)?@
```

Note that `(\d+)?` is the same as `(\d*)` (not in all cases and all flavors, but in your case it is):

```
@(?:[a-z]{2})?(lookbook)/?(\d*)(?:\.html)?@
```

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/yBOFZn)